# How to use regular expressions to extract patterns above a certain value

Tags: python, regex

I have a string. I would like to generate a regex pattern that would only print the string with a value over 0.5

```
import re

text = 'xxxx || yyy || 0.7819662242 || zzz'
     
pattern = " " #regex here

if re.search(pattern, text):
    print("Yes!")
else:
    print("No!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generic Regex

`(.* \|\| (1\.\d+|0\.[789]\d+) \|\| .*)`

### Specific Regex

`(?P<username>[\w\d]*)(\s\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\s)(?P<botprob>(1\.\d+|0\.[789]\d+))(\s\|\|\s)(\w+)`

### Description

```
/ (.* \|\| (1\.\d|0\.[789]\d+) \|\| .*) /gm

1st Capturing Group (.* \|\| (1\.\d|0\.[789]\d+) \|\| .*)
  .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
    * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
  \| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
  \| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
    matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
  
  2nd Capturing Group (1\.\d|0\.[789]\d+)
    1st Alternative 1\.\d
      1 matches the character 1 literally (case sensitive)
      \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
      \d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
    2nd Alternative 0\.[789]\d+
      0 matches the character 0 literally (case sensitive)
      \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
      Match a single character present in the list below [789]
        789 matches a single character in the list 789 (case sensitive)
      \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
        + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
    \| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
    \| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
        matches the character   literally (case sensitive)
    .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
  Global pattern flags
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
    m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/axQ8is/2)

Comment: `\w` also matches `\d`, so `[\w\d]*`  can be just `\w*`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I didn't go through his specific Regex to optimize so there might be a lot more that could be updated with the provided Specific answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> [e.rstrip() for e in tweets if re.search(r' 0\.[789]\d+ \|\|[^|]+$', e)]
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> [e.rstrip() for e in tweets if float(re.split(r'\|\|', e)[-2])>.7]
```

Either produces (`\n` added...):

```
['fasteddiekc || Wed Mar 18 07:16:32 +0000 2020 || #coronavirus shows that racists have absolutely 2 much time on their hands Firstly, those racists who hate POC &amp; Râ\x80¦ || 0.8441984525 || irrelevant',
 'Georgia_VOL || Sun Mar 22 23:40:18 +0000 2020 || If your mountain of toilet paper falls on you and kills you, did you die from the coronavirus? || 0.8548931203 || irrelevant', 
 "saintevenlive || Thu Mar 26 23:16:29 +0000 2020 || Things have been shitty enough (even before covid) that you don't have to waste time to watch shallow heavy handedâ\x80¦ || 0.8002252668000001 || irrelevant", 
 'ioncorruption || Fri Jun 19 02:23:31 +0000 2020 || I hope your father recovers from the virus as soonas possible and the family does not get infected from Covid as thâ\x80¦ || 0.7434430488 || politics']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, just minor regex alteration

```
pattern = "(?P<username>[\w\d]*)(\s\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\s.*\s\|\|\s)(?P<botprob>0\.[7-9][0-9]+)(\s\|\|\s)(\w+)"
```